# Delete Column macro for Excel works stepping through, but not when assigned to a "button" shape

Tags: excel, vba, button

Here is the code I am using, which works well stepping through it.  When I try to make it "qualified" using the workbook and sheet definitions at the top of the code, it does not work.  When I assign the macro to a shape in excel (a "delete" button) it does not work and throws a runtime 1004 error.  I have attached the code I am using.

````
  'Set wscopy = Workbooks("5 Master Enterprise Mfg Cost Forecast  w Overhead Margin and Crossover_COPY then SAVE.xlsm").Worksheets("Output w Printer")
  'Set wsDest = Workbooks("5 Master Enterprise Mfg Cost Forecast  w Overhead Margin and Crossover_COPY then SAVE.xlsm").Worksheets("Output w Printer")
  'Set wsDest3 = Workbooks("5 Master Enterprise Mfg Cost Forecast  w Overhead Margin and Crossover_COPY then SAVE.xlsm").Worksheets("CompTable")

Dim ActiveShape As Shape
Dim UserSelection As Variant
Dim col, row

    Set UserSelection = ActiveWindow.Selection

    Set ActiveShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes(UserSelection.Name)

    col = Split(ActiveShape.TopLeftCell.Address, "$")(1)
    Columns(col).EntireColumn.Delete

End Sub```
````

Comment: Runtime 1004 error can means different things. Should there be a description when the error occur? and which line does the error occur?  I cannot run your code as it is incomplete. My suggestion is to use `Debug.Print` to list the `ActiveSheet.Name` and `UserSelection.Name` to make sure they are correct.  Probably VBA failed to create `ActiveShape`.

Comment: If you call a macro from a shape then `Application.Caller` gives you the name of the clicked shape.   So `ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.EntireColumn.Delete`

Comment: Oliver, the error description is "application-defined or object-defined error."  The line that debug points me to is the "Set ActiveShape..."  I appreciate any suggestions you have.  I am  not very experienced with VBA and have been searching for this functiionality (I thought this would be a more common feature) and have not found a good solution beyond this current code.

Comment: @TimWilliams, I am not sure how to apply your suggestion.  I did replace the line for ActiveSheet with yours, but that did not run.